# React - newer 'const' version of this var?

Tags: reactjs

I'm new to React and trying to navigate the ES5/6 terrain and specifically, I want to learn how to create dynamic components using the new const method in place of the standard var x = react.createClass(){}.

What would be the newer const syntax for this var:

```
var PlaylistAlbumsList = React.createClass({

  render: function() {

    return (
      <ul className="container-fluid">
        {this.props.albumsList.map(function(albumsList){
          return (
            <li className={albumsList.className} key={albumsList.id}>
              <PlaylistAlbumInfoOverlay albumTitle={albumsList.albumTitle} albumType={albumsList.albumType} />
              <img src={albumsList.src} width='100%' />
            </li>
          )
        }.bind(this))}
      </ul>
    )

  }
});
```

Comment: `var` being replaced with `const` and that's it? Dunno why people think about `const` as having some superpowers in JS. Also, you seem to export it immediately so that `const` is meaningless because it may be required in anyway.

Comment: The issue is with passing json data.

Comment: I think what you're looking for clarity on are _stateless functional components_. Something of the form `const Component = (props) => {}`, correct?

Comment: @brad, yes. Broadly speaking I have an App.js with several children pages and I want to do an ajax call in the main App.js and make the JSON object available in any and all children pages and components. I'm going to ask a different question more specific to this as I think this question is too narrow for what I want to accomplish.

Comment: Alright, fair enough.

Comment: Stateless function components have no state, that's the point of them. :) They aren't meant to completely *replace* stateful component classes, they are meant to be used for components that *don't need state*, while you use component classes (ES6 `class` syntax or ES5 `createClass` syntax) for components that *do need state* or need to use life-cycle functions.